# Is it possible to add custome condition in filters?

Tags: handsontable

I want to add greater then and lessthen condition in below example. is it possible?
[image]

Comment: Check THis... https://handsontable.com/examples.html?_ga=2.30826361.791823177.1498031121-1412077617.1498031121&headers&dropdown-menu&filters ..

Comment: Yah but need to add grater-then and less-then condition in that.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Filter By Condition` in dropdown

**Fiddle Link :**

http://jsfiddle.net/kumarrishikesh12/wr7snuws/

[image]

Comment: Yah but need to add grater-then and less-then condition in that.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about the option **columns** of your Handsontable definition.

The option *Filters* already have conditions 'Greater than' & 'Lesser than' but they will be available only for 'numeric' data type.

If I take [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/z1bL53rt/), regardless of the data type, the conditions won't be available.

Now if I add the **columns** option in [this edited example](http://jsfiddle.net/hb03wdfc/) :

```
columns: [
  {type: 'text'},
  {type: 'numeric'},
],
```

The conditions you need will became available for the 2nd column.

Comment: But I have anchor tag for the same. and when user click on that link it will open the new page. So, if i put numaric then my html won't Work

Comment: oh yeah... the problem become much more complexe then.... Because even if it's possible to add the option manually anyway (need to check that), I'm not sure if the filter will actually work with those values / links ...